# How do change a data type of all columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas data frames. The data contains 3032 columns. All the columns are 'object' datatype. How do I  convert all the columns to 'float' datatype?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need convert integers and floats columns use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for apply for all columns:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

working same like:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x))
```

If some columns contains strings (so converting failed) is possible add `errors='coerce'` for repalce it to missing values `NaN`:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the df from a file you can do the same when reading using converters in case you want to apply a customized function, or using dtype to specify the data type you want.